# Check if 2 subspaces with 1 element each, are equal

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a \in R$, $a \neq 0$

$W,U \in M_2(R)$ are subspaces, such that

\begin{align}
W &= \operatorname{Sp}\biggl\{\begin{pmatrix}a&4a^2-3a \\ 1&4a-3\end{pmatrix}\biggr\}, \\
U &= \operatorname{Sp}\biggl\{\begin{pmatrix}a^{-1}&a \\ a&a^3\end{pmatrix}\biggr\}.
\end{align}

What values of $a$ give: $W=U$?

---

Here is my way, how do I make it better?

Let $t\in R$. Check conditions that gives $tU = W$.

$$t\begin{pmatrix}a^{-1}&a \\ a&a^3\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}a&4a^2-3a \\ 1&4a-3\end{pmatrix}$$
So
\begin{align}
ta^{-1} &= a \tag{1} \\
ta &= 4a^2-3a \tag{2} \\
ta &= 1 \tag{3} \\
ta^3 &= 4a - 3 \tag{4}.
\end{align}

From $(2)$ and $(3)$:
$$ta = 1 = 4a^2-3a \Rightarrow a = 1,-\frac{1}{4}.$$

From $(4)$:
$$ta^3=taa^2=4a-3 \Rightarrow a^2 = 4a-3 \Rightarrow a = 1,3$$

From $(1)$:
$$ta^{-1}=taa^{-2} = a \Rightarrow a^{-2} = a \Rightarrow a = 1.$$

So the only value of a that solves the equations is $a=1$.

Comment: Your sets of matrices are not subspaces (not stable by linear combinations).

Comment: You write $W=Sp$ and $U=Sp$. So $W=U$. Otherwise $U$ can only have a matrix with $a_{21}=1$ if $a=1$. So we do not need to do any calculation (except for checking that the matrix with every entry equal to $1$ is in both sets).

Comment: but for example $Sp(3) = Sp(2)$ but $2 \neq 3$ and for $t = 1.5 \Rightarrow t2=3=3$ so how can you compare it directly without the scalar t?

Comment: You'd shorten it if you looked at the $(1,1)$ and $(2,1)$ place first, you get $a=1$ at once and then only need check the other two places.